# Make \overrightarrow colored

Tags: color, arrows

It is possible to make `\overrightarrow` (the arrow itself not what is under it) colored? (LaTeX)

Comment: Should all instances, or just selected instances, of `\overrightarrow` be colored non-black?

Comment: Just selected. Well, I have decided to denote it other way. The question is no more of value for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following elementary redefinition inserts the appropriate colour, while setting whatever is underneath the arrow in `\color{black}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,xcolor}

\let\oldoverrightarrow\overrightarrow
\renewcommand{\overrightarrow}[2][]{{%
  \if$#1$\else\color{#1}\fi% Optional argument given...
   \oldoverrightarrow{\color{black}#2}%
}}

\begin{document}

$A \quad \overrightarrow{\text{some text}} \quad B 
   \quad \overrightarrow[red]{\text{some text}} \quad C$

\end{document}
```

If the preservation of the current colour is required, you can use the following definition:

```
\renewcommand{\overrightarrow}[2][]{%
  {\colorlet{thecurrentcolour}{.}\if$#1$\else\color{#1}\fi%
   \oldoverrightarrow{\color{thecurrentcolour}#2}%
  }%
}
```

It stores the current colour - `.` as `thecurrentcolour`, and uses that (instead of `black`) for the text underneath the arrow.